# python - pygame get mouse position via threading

Tags: python, sockets, multithreading

I have made a server - client program and I have my main loop where I send images of the client to the server. this loop is slow, so I opened a threading before the while True loop.

The threading sends the position of the cursor from the server to the client.
the problem is that it gets only the first position and then maintain it. like:
(192,500)
(192,500)
(192,500)
(192,500)
(192,500)
...
no matter if my cursor moves.
I tried already:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    pass
pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

but it only works without the threading.
something with the thread doesn't appear to communicate with the screen from the actual main program.

server threading function:

```
def mouseControl(Socket):
while True:                                      
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    Socket.send(str(pos[0])+" "+str(pos[1]))
    a = Socket.recv(1024)
```

client threading function:`

```
def mouseControl(Socket):
while True:
    pos = Socket.recv(1024)
    pos=pos.split()
    x,y = int(pos[0]),int(pos[1])
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    Socket.send("Allright")
```

I can't use the win32api.getCursorPos() because I need the relative position of the other computer's screen.
any solution?